# gif image not looping

Tags: image, photoshop, gif

I have created a gif in photoshop.  It has two frames displayed for 4 seconds each and is on a loop forever.

For some reason the image freezes on the second frame and does not continue to load in some browsers (The exact information about browsers and / or versions is unclear at the moment but it has happened in the latest version of chrome).

The image is embedded in the code in the standard way, no javascript is used and nothing is changing the element.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?  Everything I have searched for so far seems to result in people saying "Oh, I forgot to put make the gif loop forever" instead of any real reasons for causing this problem.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Sorry I didn't think about putting an image in the original post.  He is an example of one advert which doesn't seem to work.

[image: example image]

Comment: You should at least upload the gif. Right now, with that info provided, you can try it at [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia)

Comment: @TomášZato Thank you for pointing that out.  I have now added a link to an image that seems to freeze.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help. It displays correctly in all my browsers. (Opera, Mozzila Firefox and Google Chrome). You should make sure if it is not connection problem. As well, come server sided compression could harm image. This is all I can figure out.

Comment: @TomášZato Thank you for trying.  I'm not sure what else I can do from here..

Comment: On your place, I would create image in different program, to see, whether it is image, what is wrong. If you will get same result it means image is not wrong at all. According to my results with your upload, this is much likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Because the current image displays correctly in everything I've tryed so far, try to create image in different application.
Some applications you may try:

1. [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/) - [tutorial](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/)
2. [Some freeware crap](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-gif-animator.htm).

I'd vote for GIMP. Its complicated, but its free and it has wide user suport.

#### If you still fail...

Now its time to check the enviroment. First, open the image on different machine. Maybe there is something wrong with your browser instalation. In this case, reinstall.
Try to upload on different server. Maybe your browser does not correctly decompress deflated data or has other communication issues.